# JSF2 Exception in accessing methods in multilevel hierarchy

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans

I have a zoos class with array list of zoo objects and in zoos there is list of animals. Accessing the animals properties works cool but accessing membermethods leads to exception.

**//Zoos class with object of Animals,Trees**

```
@ManagedBean
public @SessionScoped class Zoos {
    private String name;
    private String description;

        private Animals animals=new Animals ();

    public void setAnimals(Animals animals) {
        this.Animals = Animals;
    }

    public Animals getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }
        //All the getters and setters
}
```

**//Animals Class**

```
public class Animals implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name; 
    private String breed;
        static final ArrayList<Animal> apbp 
    = new ArrayList<Animal>(); 

       //Getters and setters...
       //Add animal in the list
    public String addAnimal()
        { 
            Animal abp = new Animal(name);
            abp.setbreed(breed);
            apbp.add(abp);
        name="";
        natPoolName="";
        defaultPublicFlag=false;
        defaultShareableFlag=false;
        enabled=false;
        return "success";

        }

}
```

**//Animal class**

```
public class Animal{

    private String name; 
    private String breed;

       //Getters and setters

}
```

**Calling the attributes of the Animals class as**
zoos.animal.name **works well.**

**But calling the member function 
zoos.animals.addAnimal from *.xhtml as

```
<h:commandButton id="ok" value="Ok" action="#{zoos.animals.addAnimal}" oncomplete="#{rich:element('mypanel')}.style.display='none'; return false;" />
```

this doesn't work and gives exception as**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$4.invokeContextCallback(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:289)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1253)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:672)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:284)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:177)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:143)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
```

I am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: have added the facelet code

Comment: Try using syntax with `()`: `#{zoos.animals.addAnimal()}`

Comment: it didn't  solve the problem.

Comment: What is EL version? Also try to add `animals` initialization in `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: @user2224083, is this all of the stacktrace?

Comment: Did you clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart after changing the code? The exception suggests that JSF miserably failed to restore the requested view which has got nothing to do with the changed component action (unless you changed other things in the view, or actually did things differently as compared to the code posted so far). Further, posting the *entire* stacktrace and exact JSF impl/version would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think NullPointerException was for jsf life cycle treat with `#{zoos.animals.addAnimal}`
as animals setter and getter , so i prefer to add method in your bean and use it directly:

```
@ManagedBean
public @SessionScoped class Zoos {
    private String name;
    private String description;

        private Animals animals=new Animals ();

    public void setAnimals(Animals animals) {
        this.Animals = Animals;
    }

    public Animals getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void addAnimalInZoo(){
        if(getAnimals()!=null) {
                getAnimals().addAnimal();
        }
    }
        //All the getters and setters
}
```

And in your page use `addAnimalInZoo()` direct:

```
<h:commandButton id="ok" value="Ok" action="#{zoos.addAnimalInZoo}" oncomplete="#{rich:element('mypanel')}.style.display='none'; return false;" />
```